# Get data from mongodb according with a value in express route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I want to get data from mongodb according with one value from an input. I implemented this, but i didn't manage to pass the value from front end to the query:

**Here is the code:**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const ejs = require("ejs");
app.set("views engine", "ejs");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
let urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/Test", { useNewUrlParser: true });
const userScheme = mongoose.Schema(
  { name: String, age: Number },
  { versionKey: false }
);
const User = mongoose.model("users", userScheme);

// Get data from input and send it to mangodb
app.post("/", urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
  // res.send('welcome, ' + req.body.newName)
  console.log(req.body.newName);
  const myname = req.body.newName;
});
// Fetch data from mangodb
User.find({ name: myname }, function(err, result) {
  mongoose.disconnect();
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  // Send data to ejs file
  console.log(result);
  const a = result;
  app.use("/", function(request, response) {
    response.render("index", { user: a });
  });
});
// Create server
app.listen(4000, function() {
  console.log("Example app listening on port 3000!");
});
```

Comment: Why is your User.find() outside of the app.post and my do you use mongoose.disconnect() inside the User.find() ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Please use following code
app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
  const myname = req.body.newName;

  // Fetch data from mangodb
  User.find({name:myname},function(err, result){
     if(err) return console.log(err);
     const a = result;
     return res.render("index", { user: a});
   });
})
```